# switch statement only returning default case no matter what case value I enter

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm trying to set up a program that will tell what day of the week it is based on the user input of a number from 1 to 7.  Every time the program executes though, it returns the default case message, saying an improper value was entered.  This happens for all case entries 1-7.  Here's the setup of the program (excluding the header):

```
//author: Ethan Adams
//date: 10/09/14
//purpose: to determine the day of the week based on user input value

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int week_day; //value entered by user

    printf("Enter the number of the week's day (1-7):\n");//prompt
    scanf("%d", &week_day); //input value

switch(week_day){
    case '1':
        printf("The day of the week is Sunday.\n");
        break;//exit switch

    case '2':
        printf("The day of the week is Monday.\n");
        break;//exit switch

    case '3':
        printf("The day of the week is Tuesday.\n");
        break;//exit switch

    case '4':
        printf("The day of the week is Wednesday.\n");
        break;//exit switch

    case '5':
        printf("The day of the week is Thursday.\n");
        break;//exit switch

    case '6':
        printf("The day of the week is Friday.\n");
        break;//exit switch

    case '7':
        printf("The day of the week is Saturday.\n");
        break;//exit switch

    default:
        printf("Improper value entered.  Please try again.\n");
        break;//exit switch
}//end switch selection

system ("pause");
}//end main
```

Also, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 if that affects anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your switch case is for `char` value. Notice you have cases as `case '1':`, `case '2':`,...

So you can either change the case statement from `case '1':` to `case 1:`

Or

Change the data type of `week_day` variable to `char`. i.e.

`int week_day;` to `char week_day;`.

After you change the data type of `week_day` variable make sure you make changes in your `scanf` statement.

Change `scanf("%d", &week_day);` to `scanf(" %c", &week_day);`